# jQuery/JS: Copy the contents of a class and print it somewhere else on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a class called `test-parent`, as below, I'd like to copy the contents of the two UL elements and prepend the content somewhere else on the page.

```
   <div class="test-parent">
    <hr>
    <strong>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
    </div>
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
(function($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( ".options_group").prepend( " <p>Test</p>" );
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Essentially all I need to do is prepend the two UL elements from within the class to the options_group class. Does anyone know how I might achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Where is options_group class in your HTML? And you've to close the </strong> (just saying)

Comment: It's nested within a myriad of other classed and divs, is this important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this , simply can  be dome using each() and clone function().
As you said you need the ul elements somewhere else , or if you just need the content inside the ul need to modify accordingly

```js
(function($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        //$( ".options_group").prepend( " <p>Test</p>" );
        $('.test-parent ul').each(function(){
          $( ".options_group").append($(this).clone());
        });   
    });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
ul{
   background:red;
   height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

.options_group{

  clear:both;
  border:1px solid black; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


   <div class="test-parent">
    <hr>
     <strong>
     <ul style="list-style-type:none">1</ul>
     <ul style="list-style-type:none">2</ul>
      </strong>

    </div>

 <div class="options_group">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jQuerys [clone function](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to clone the uls:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".copy").prepend($(".test-parent ul").clone());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-parent">
  <hr/>
  <ul style="list-style-type:none">
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
    <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="copy">
</div>
```